# How to save sklearn model after fitting in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am fitting two sklearn models in a for loop with pipeline, and trying to name them separate and predict with this pipeline later,

```
names = ["Linear", "Elastic"]
models = [LinearRegression(),ElasticNet()]
model_fit = [x + 'fit' for x in names]

for name, model, fits in zip(names, models, model_fit):
    steps = [('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),(name, model)]
    pipe = Pipeline(steps)
    fits = pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

But I am not able to predict it in a different loop.

```
for i, model in enumerate(model_fit):
   predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

receiving following error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

How can I fit and retrieve these two models as different names?

Comment: `names = ["Linear", "Elastic"]` and `model_fit = [x + 'fit' for x in names]`, these two lines lead to `model_fit` being a list of strings. Perhaps you want to work with `models` list instead.

Comment: can you please explain with the above example

Comment: did you mean `for i, model in enumerate(models):`

Comment: No,  because that doesn't take care of my pipeline. I am trying to give every pipeline kind of a new name

Comment: If I understand correctly, `model_fit` is the name of the pipeline. A name can't predict since, it isn't a model. So you need to store the fitted models in another array and use them in the second loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `model_fit` variable is a string array so you should not use it in the second for loop. What you should do is store the models in another array and use it.

```
names = ["Linear", "Elastic"]
models = [LinearRegression(),ElasticNet()]
model_fit = [x + 'fit' for x in names]
fitted_models = []

for name, model, fits in zip(names, models, model_fit):
    steps = [('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),(name, model)]
    pipe = Pipeline(steps)
    fits = pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
    fitted_models.append(fits)

for i, model in enumerate(fitted_models):
   predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I was missing something